# MessageGateway is coming as null

Tags: osgi, aem

I am trying to send email in participant step. I have written a email service which uses the Message Gateway to send emails.

But MessageGateway messageGateway = this.messageGatewayService.getGateway(Email.class); this line is giving messageGateway as null.

I went through a number of posts and everywhere it is mentioned that if the SMTP details are not mentioned properly in Day Cq Mail service then it comes as null.

But I have configured it properly because if I select the senEmail checkbox in the dynamic step then AEM is able to send default emails using this. So I am sure SMTP is not something which can be at fault. Do we need something else also so that the messageGateway doesnot come as null. I am using AEM 6.1 SP3.

Thanks,

Tushar

Comment: I have seen issues with Email.class in some versions. Can you try HtmlEmail.class instead?

Comment: I have used HtmlEmail.class also, even that doesnot work out

Comment: Change the log level to trace and see if thers is any useful info in there. Normally it's some bad config.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the com.day.cq.cq-mailer bundle in the environment was the solution that worked for me.

The MessageGatewayService contains a hashSet of gateways. If you delete or move your Day CQ Mail Service configuration, a new gateway is added to the hashSet. The messageGatewayService.getGateway() only retrieves one DefaultMailService from the hashSet, and it could be one with cfg null inside, although there exists one configured correctly. Only way to clean this up is by restarting the bundle.

Any subsequent updates to theDefaultMailService config work fine. This only happens when you delete/move your config in your environment.